# Transistion Matrix Confusion

Tags: linear-algebra

Let α={α1,α2,α3,α4}, β={β1,β2,β3,β4} and γ={γ1,γ2,γ3,γ4}be a bases of a vector space V. Suppose we have

β1=4α1

β2=6α1+8α2

β3=4α1+4α2+7α3

β4=2α1+3α2+7α3+5α4

and

γ1=9β4

γ2=8β3+8β4

γ3=5β2+3β3+4β4

γ4=7β1+10β2+4β3+9β4

Find the transistion matrix from the basis α to the basis γ"

I have tried this four times and each attempt was incorrect. I keep getting

$\begin{pmatrix}18 & 27 & 63 & 45 \\ 48 & 56 & 77 & 40 \\ 50 & 64 & 49 & 20\\ 122 &123&91 & 45\end{pmatrix}$

Can anyone find a different answer than this? I'm getting no where even when I substitute directly. My log is as follows $An=b$, $Mb = c$, then $AnM = c$, which is the same as $(AM)n = c$. This means we can just multiply the two coefficient matrices of what we are given. I think.

Comment: What is the exact definition of the transition matrix. Generally I would expect this to be something that turns the coefficients of a vector in the alpha basis to the coefficients of the same vector in the gamma basis. The matrix you have seems to be one that transforms the basis vectors into each other and not necessarily their coefficients. Generally the transformation laws aren't the same (e.g. contravariant vs covariant quantities).

Answer (score 0):

From the information you've given, we know that the transition matrix from $\beta$ to $\alpha$ is given by
$$
I_{\beta\to\alpha} = 
\pmatrix{
4&6&4&2\\
0&8&4&3\\
0&0&7&7\\
0&0&0&5\\
}
$$
Similarly, we have
$$
I_{\gamma\to\beta} = 
\pmatrix{
9&8&5&7\\
0&8&3&10\\
0&0&4&4\\
0&0&0&9
}
$$
EDITORIAL NOTE: I had the wrong order before, here's what it should have been.

If you want to go from $\alpha$ to $\gamma$, you'll have to calculate
$$
I_{\alpha\to\gamma} = I_{\gamma\to\beta}^{-1} I_{\beta\to\alpha}^{-1}
= (I_{\beta\to\alpha} I_{\gamma\to\beta})^{-1}
$$
I hope that clears things up.

---

In my own calculations, I found
$$
I_{\gamma\to\alpha} = I_{\beta\to\alpha}I_{\gamma\to\beta} =
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 36 & 80 & 54 & 113 \\
 0 & 64 & 40 & 123 \\
 0 & 0 & 28 & 91 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 45 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and then 
$$
I_{\alpha\to\gamma}=(I_{\gamma\to\beta}I_{\beta\to\alpha})^{-1} =
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac{1}{36} & -\frac{5}{144} & -\frac{1}{252} & \frac{43}{1296} \\
 0 & \frac{1}{64} & -\frac{5}{224} & \frac{7}{2880} \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{28} & -\frac{13}{180} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{45} \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
= 
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0.0277778 & -0.0347222 & -0.00396825 & 0.033179 \\
 0. & 0.015625 & -0.0223214 & 0.00243056 \\
 0. & 0. & 0.0357143 & -0.0722222 \\
 0. & 0. & 0. & 0.0222222 \\
\end{array}
\right)\\
= \frac 1{181440}
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 5040 & -6300 & -720 & 6020 \\
 0 & 2835 & -4050 & 441 \\
 0 & 0 & 6480 & -13104 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 4032 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
This, of course, is assuming I understood what you mean by "transition matrix", which I assumed is the same as a "[change-of-basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis)" matrix.

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it another go.

Comment: Ah, I tried doing that and got the incorrect answer with no more attempts. I'm still interested in the answer though

Comment: Sorry to hear about that. I've added what I got for the answer.

Comment: It seems I had it wrong before; my order of multiplication was backwards.